Concave mirrors and real images
Recently, I watched a video in which a concave lens was demonstrated forming all types of images from various distance points. Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zv-4Zh-9R4&ab_channel=PhysicsDemos
In said video, It is seen that the images formed are 'seen' inside the mirror, but since concave mirrors form real images, Why is it still perceived to be 'inside' the mirror?

This HyperPhysics page might help - Image Formation

Concave mirrors also form virtual images, for real objects inside the focal point..  A concave shaving mirror is one example...

So, as the man was standing very close to the centre of curvature of the concave mirror, the light from the man gets reflected by concave mirror and forms a real image near the centre of curvature but the reflected light from the concave mirror also enters the the eye of the man and falls on retina(of the eye). Therefore it seems to the man that the image was formed inside the mirror as the reflected rays were coming from the mirror.
